# SVG css height/width does not applied

Tags: css, svg

I try to display SVG icon of a certain size.

This doesn't work (size of icon is huge):

```
<svg style="width: 10px; height: 10px;">
  <use xlink:href="#...">
</svg>
```

This works:

```
<svg width="10px" height="10px">
  <use xlink:href="#...">
</svg>
```

The question is why? What is wrong with Icon? I had other projects where css height/width worked in such cases.

Svg icon code:

```
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:odm="http://product.corel.com/CGS/11/cddns/"
   xml:space="preserve"
   width="180pt"
   height="188pt"
   style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd"
   viewBox="0 0 8268 11692"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   id="svg614"
<sodipodi:namedview
   id="base" /><defs
   id="defs615"><style
   type="text/css"
   id="style616"><![CDATA[
    .fil0 {fill:#000000}
   ]]></style></defs><g
   id="Layer 1"
   transform="matrix(4.552447,0,0,4.540583,-8401.163,-13199.48)"><path
   class="fil0"
   d="...."
   id="path618" /></g></svg>
```

UPDATE:

This svg is inside another svg element.

Comment: give the svg elem the same `viewBox` attr as the actual svg

Comment: This doesn't help

Comment: The markup should give the same results. Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score -2):

You can try wrapping the SVG in a `<div> <svg> </svg> </div>` and set the height of the div it does not work at all.

Comment: I think it can not do so, this svg is inside another svg element.

Comment: Is this an answer? Sounds more like a question to me... all in all, this answer has comment quality at best.